# How to display scroll bar in flexible height with parent component is flex: 1

Tags: css

This is code example.

```html
<main>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="content">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
      </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

```
.panel {
    flex: 1;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    .content {
      flex: 1;
      background: #a1a1a1;
      overflow: auto;
      li {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          height: 20vh;
      }
    }
}
```

More detail in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/steven11329/pen/ZEaGvKr)

I know it would be work with `max-height:<number>px`

But I want to **panel's height flexible**.
How to display scroll bar on panel content only ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly - your html is invalid - the only valid parent of an `li` is a `ul`

To answer your question - you need to set a height (in px / % / em / rem of an ancestor element and then just setting height to 100% on your content will allow it to have overflow.

```css
.panel {
height: 10rem; 
overflow: hidden;
border: solid 1px blue
}

.header {
 padding: 8px 16px;
}
.content {
 height: 100%;
  border: solid 1px red;
  background: #a1a1a1;
  overflow: auto;
}

li {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 20vh;
    border: solid 1px black
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="content">
        <ul>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
          <li>test</li>
        </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: But I want to panel's height flexible. Not only content.

Comment: an ancestor somewhere has to have a height set - all children elements can relatee pooportionally to that height but something must have a limit set otherwise the content in the overflowing element will just render down the page and all containing elements will just stretch to accomodate them and nothing wiill have an overflow.